# PHP validation class for username, email, and password

Tags: php, object-oriented, validation

I'm relatively new to PHP OOP, currently I'm practising how to use it, however I am not really certain I'm building my classes correctly, I think perhaps I'm missing something out but I'm not entirely sure what, any advice would be appreciated

Class

```
class Validation 
{
    private 
    $password,
    $repeatPassword,
    $username,
    $email;

    private static
    $minPassword = 7,
    $confirmPassword,
    $minUsername = 3,
    $maxUsername = 14,
    $validEmail;

    public static function validateEmail($email)
    {   
        return (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) != self::$validEmail);
    }   
    public static function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return(strlen($password) >= self::$minPassword);
    }

    public static function validatecheckbox($agree)
    {
        return(!empty($terms) >= self::$checked);
    }
    public static function validateRepeatPassword($repeatPassword,$password) 
    { 
            return $repeatPassword === $password; 

    }  
    public static function validateUsername($username)
    {
            return strlen($username) >= self::$minUsername 
            && (strlen($username)) <= self::$maxUsername 
            && (filter_var($username ,  FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,["options"=> [ "regexp" => "/^[\p{L}0-9\s]+$/u"]]) == TRUE);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
    $errors = array();

 $fields = array( 
  'username' => array( 
    'validator' => 'validateUsername', 
    'message'   => 'What is your username?' 
  ), 
  'email' => array( 
    'validator' => 'validateEmail', 
    'message'   => 'Please enter a valid email', 
  ), 
  'password' => array( 
    'validator' => 'validatePassword', 
    'message'   => 'Password must be a minimum of seven characters' 
  )
);  

if(!Validation::validateRepeatPassword($password, $repassword)) 
{ 
    $errors[] = ["name" => "repassword", "error" => "Passwords must match"]; 
}
foreach($post as $key => $value) 
    {
  if(isset($fields[$key])) 
    {
            if(!Validation::{$fields[$key]['validator']}($value)) 
            {
                $errors[] = ['name' => $key, 'error' => $fields[$key]['message']];
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes towards the bottom `foreach($post as $key => $value) 
    {
  if(isset($fields[$key])) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your class is good and does what it is supposed to do, except in `validalidatecheckbox()` (you are using variables that doesn't exist).

Also I would do this changes:

- Remove this code (it's unused):

  `private $password,
      $repeatPassword,
      $username,
      $email;`
- Change this to constants, so you can use it elsewhere:

  `private static $minPassword = 7,
      $confirmPassword,
      $minUsername = 3,
      $maxUsername = 14,
      $validEmail;`

So your class should look like this:

```
class Validation
{
    const MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 7;
    const MIN_USERNAME_LENGTH = 3;
    const MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH = 14;

    // rest of your code
```

Also, I strongly recommend you to check [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1) and [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) to make your code look standard-like.

Comment: Thank you I honestly wasn't sure if `const` would be be the correct thing to use, I will read over both links too